# Solving for two parameters using `optim()` in R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, optimization, sapply

I'm trying to find `shape1` and `shape2` in `dbeta()` such that the answer from `dbeta()` for the two input values: `.6` and `.8` become `3`.

I'm using the below `optim()` but don't get exact result, that is I expect getting values for `shape1` and `shape2` that when used with `.6` and `.8` give `3` and `3`, but they don't, why?

```
f <- function(x) {
 y <- c(3, 3) - dbeta(c(.6, .8), shape1 = x[1],  shape2 = x[2])  
}

AA = optim(c(1, 1), function(x) sum(f(x)^2), control = list(reltol = (.Machine$double.eps))) 

parms = unname(AA$par)

dbeta(c(.6, .8), parms[1], parms[2]) # Here I expect to get `3` for `.6` and `.8` but I don't.
```

Comment: I am not sure what is going on here, but when I play around a bit with the parameters, for example setting `f` to `c(1, 1) - ...` and the set the initial values of `optim` to c(0.5, 0.5)`, or setting `f` to `c(2, 2) - ...` with the same initial values, I get the expected result. Setting one or another of these values to a larger magnitude, throws off the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a brief look at this.  I don't think there's any problem with the fit: here's a picture of the likelihood surface:

```
library(emdbook)
cc <- curve3d(g(c(x,y)),xlim=c(1,20),ylim=c(1,20),
              sys3d="none")
pp <- which(cc$z==min(cc$z),arr.ind=TRUE)
png("betasurf.png")
with(cc,image(x,y,z))
points(parms[1],parms[2],pch=16)
points(cc$x[pp[1]],cc$y[pp[2]],pch=1)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Filled circle is the fitted value, open circle is the minimum of the grid; I think the difference is just numerical fuzz (I zoomed in a few times to make sure). In any case, there's no evidence of anything weird like multiple optima.

I believe the issue is just that you've set up a set of pair of points that *can't be simultaneously matched by **any** Beta distribution*; `optim()` is giving you the best possible fit ...

```
png("betatmp.png")
curve(dbeta(x,parms[1],parms[2]),from=0,to=1)
points(c(0.6,0.8),c(3,3),pch=16)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ben, I was wondering if you might know the answer to [*this interesting question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857624/r-function-that-uses-its-output-as-its-own-input-repeatedly)?